# Why I can't access to my Methods?

Tags: c#, repository

I have some order like this :

```
IRepository(dll) -> IBaseRepository -> IEntityRepository 

 |                        |               |

Repositoyr(dll) -> BaseRepository -> EntityRepository
```

I'm using unity service locator and I defined some methods in `IBaseRepository` and Implement them in `BaseRepository` ( to be able to use them in all of my Entity repositories )

now when I make an instance of `EntityRepository` in my Actions , I have access to all of Repository methods but the `BaseRepository` methods are not shown !?

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
     void Add(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
        string recordStatusDescription);
    void Update(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
       string recordStatusDescription);
    void Remove(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
        string recordStatusDescription);
}




public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : GenericRepository<TEntity>, IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
    //public abstract void Add(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
    //    string recordStatusDescription);

    public void Add(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
        string recordStatusDescription)
    {
        entity.RecordStatus = recordStatus;
        entity.RecordStatusDescription = recordStatusDescription;
        entity.CreatedBy = currentUserNationalCode;
        entity.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        entity.CreatorIPAddress = currentUserIp;
        this.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
        string recordStatusDescription)
    {
        entity.RecordStatus = recordStatus;
        entity.RecordStatusDescription = recordStatusDescription;
        entity.ModifiedBy = currentUserNationalCode;
        entity.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        entity.ModifierIPAddress = currentUserIp;
        this.Update(entity);     
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
        string recordStatusDescription)
    {
        entity.RecordStatus = recordStatus;
        entity.RecordStatusDescription = recordStatusDescription;
        entity.RemovedBy = currentUserNationalCode;
        entity.RemovedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        entity.RemoverIPAddress = currentUserIp;
        entity.IsRemoved = true;
        this.Update(entity);
    }
}
```

and my `IEntityRepository` and `EnityRepository` are empty :

```
public class [Entity]Repository : BaseRepository<Organization>, IOrganizationRepository
{    
}
```

even if I add some method to my Entity repository, I can't access it.
Base Entity is class contain of some log fields that are in all of my entities.

Comment: Can you post the code also.

Comment: Please, post some relevant code.

Comment: How do you instantiate you class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class Repository : BaseRepository<Organization>, IOrganizationRepository
{
   public void DoSomethingFancy(TEntity entity, string currentUserNationalCode, string currentUserIp, byte recordStatus,
    string recordStatusDescription)
  {
     base.Add(entity, currentUserNationalCode, currentUserIp, recordStatus,  recordStatusDescription);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but my problem was fundamental , I talked with senior Programmer ( who designed our Repository classes ) and he said that Repository is using disposable instance and we can't access to derived class instanced in our code ( without using disposable instance , it work fine but our program has to use repositories disposable instances due heavy traffic )   .... in the end of day he decide that he should modify Repository to be able to use this method .... so It wasn't a mistake at all ... but thanks for your help and time that you spend to helping me !